# How to accumulate facts into a value in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Here are the facts:

```
% structure: salary([Name, Last Name], salary_amount).

salary([bartholomew, simpson], 0).    
salary([homer, simpson], 40000).    
salary([lisa, simpson], 500).    
salary([maggie, simpson], 0).    
salary([marge, simpson], 10000).
```

Here is my predicate for printing out all of the salaries

```
entire_family(X,Income) :-
    bagof(_,salary([_, X],Income), _).
```

which outputs

```
Income = 0 ;    
Income = 40000 ;    
Income = 500 ;    
Income = 0 ;    
Income = 10000.
```

I need it to output

```
Income: 50500 (total salaries of the Simpson family)
```

If anyone has any hints for me please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer is in Prolog which is a logic programming language, the solution is more easily understood as a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) problem which [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)) the facts to a list then [folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) the list into a single value.

To filter the facts into a list

```
salary_to_list(L) :-
    findall(S,salary(_,S),L).
```

Example:

```
?- salary_to_list(L).
L = [0, 40000, 500, 0, 10000].
```

To fold the list into a value

```
sum(L,S) :-
    foldl(plus,L,0,S).
```

Example:

```
?- foldl(plus,[2,3,4],0,S).
S = 9.
```

Putting the two together for your question.

```
entire_family(Income) :-
    salary_to_list(L),
    sum(L,Income).
```

Example:

```
?- entire_family(Income).
Income = 50500.
```

---

The entire source

```
:- use_module(library(apply)).

salary([bartholomew, simpson], 0).
salary([homer, simpson], 40000).
salary([lisa, simpson], 500).
salary([maggie, simpson], 0).
salary([marge, simpson], 10000).

salary_to_list(L) :-
    findall(S,salary(_,S),L).

sum(L,S) :-
    foldl(plus,L,0,S).

entire_family(Income) :-
    salary_to_list(L),
    sum(L,Income).
```

---

References:

SWI-Prolog:
[Finding all Solutions to a Goal](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions) - findall/3
[library(apply): Apply predicates on a list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply) -foldl/4
[Special purpose integer arithmetic](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=logic-int-arith) - plus/3

The Power of Prolog:
[Higher-order Predicates](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/metapredicates)

Comment: Thank you so much! now the next question or situation would be if you had multiple families?

Comment: @BartAlen Post a new question. They don't cost anything, and for each question you have more opportunity to get more points.

Comment: Well to make it easier how would I add the condition of the last name of everyone in the family? @Guy Coder

Comment: @BartAlen Seriously, post a new question and link this one to it. I won't give you an answer to these questions as comments or edits to this question. This question is done; put a fork in it.

Comment: Well I figured it out but thank you though, your explanation definitely showed me I was missing a few other steps to include

Comment: @BartAlen In reality I would not have made the two other predicates separate, I only did it hear so that they would have names and be easier for you and others learning from it to follow. Think lambda functions.